# bounds] not changing when going landscape

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I have written an application that has a UIViewController which displays another UIViewController when in portrait mode and a different UIViewController when in landscape.

When I go landscape I will be drawing/placing things so I need to get the landscape co-ordinates. Below is the code that triggers the new view when the iPhone rotates. The code below is how this view is loaded.

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)x
  duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(x)) 
{
    NSLog(@"Going Portrait");

} else if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(x)) 
{
    NSLog(@"Going Landscape");
    if (activeView != [graphViewController view]) 
    {
        [containerView addSubview:[graphViewController view]];  
    }
}
}
```

My problem is that when the

```
-(void)loadView {
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
NSLog(@"GraphViewController: Screenbounds %@", NSStringFromCGRect(screenBounds));
}
```

in GraphViewController returns, it produces:  **GraphViewController: Screenbounds {{0, 0}, {320, 480}}**

which isn't the landscape co-oridinates and thus my drawing is incorrect. 
How do I make it so GraphViewController has the correct co-ordinates when it calls **[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];**?

Many thanks

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is with the hierarchy you have built. What it sounds like is when you add in the 2nd view controller, it think's its in portrait mode (even though you are in landscape). I think what will fix your problem is implementing the

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
```

methods in both your main viewcontroller and the graphviewcontroller.

However, I don't think this is a good path to go down. Is there a specific reason you are using uiviewcontrollers instead of just uiviews to display the different interfaces?

If you can go to straight UIViews, and then just do something like

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)x
  duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
   if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(x)) 
   {
       NSLog(@"Going Portrait");

   } 
   else if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(x)) 
   {
       NSLog(@"Going Landscape");
       if (activeView != graphView) 
       {
           containerView = graphView;
           //OR
           [containerView addSubview:graphView];
       }
   }
}
```

I think you will be better off in the long run, but your choice.

Comment: Thanks - I don't have major reason for using ViewControllers but I am learning so your advice is good.  One of the view's is going to hold a UITableView so I guess you have to use a ViewController to hold it.

Comment: A UITableView is just a view like anything else. If you want to use a UITableView, you dont need another controller (u already have one). The only thing that you need is to tell your UIViewController to implement the UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate methods. But again, either implementation should work, but its going to get cluttered really quickly IMO. Secondly, did implementing the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: methods have any affect?

Comment: I am going to have a go at the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation tonight so will let you know.  Thank you for your advice above I now see what your saying - will look at modifying my code.

Comment: I took your advice and recoded it so there is one view controller.  This then creates 2 views which are used depending if the iPhone is portrait or landscape.  Many thanks.